# Can boys talk to girls in islam

Tags: halal-haram, relationships

I really want to know if i'm doing something haram. I like this boy and he likes me too, we chat to eachother but i don't look him as my boyfriend, were just close friends, we want to marry eatcchother in the future. Am i doing something haram?

Answer (score 1):

Assalamualikum.

what makes you think you're 'just friends' if you're both willing to get married soon?
This might be just friendship for now, but it would   eventually lead to haram tendencies. 
Chatting with him, talking with him, spending time with him, might just seem like  friendship for now. But shaytan is patient. He'll slowly make you commit zina of the heart, or eyes or other worse sins. 
So it is better to let your parents know about this, they'll help you either get married soon, or decide somthing else which is right for you.

"**when two people are alone together (illegally) ,then the third is shaitaan.**"
(Bukhari)

So may Allah protect us all.

Answer (score -1):

Always, if such a question arises for you, first refer to your intellect, then study the Quran and then the life of the Prophet.  So Is the relationship between two people of the opposite sex logically wrong?  My mind tells me that relationship with any human being is not wrong if it does not harm myself or others,so what could harm us in a relationship?
the Quran says that human can grow in social relations, any one in their social activities is responsible for their actions, the only thing could really harm ourselves or others is sexual actions outside of  marital relations, so god says If your sexual instinct and the need to have sex bother you as much as you can not keep it to yourself , get married!  Marriage also means sticking to one person for a period of time that you agree on.  So if you have a relationship with a person and stick to it and be responsible for it, you actually married him and there is no problem in the relationship with him.
And you need to understand something : people usually use religion to excuse their bad behavior or limit others . So if in any relationship in your life , Always pay attention to your behavior and actions, put yourself in the opposite person's place and see if your behavior and your relationship with that person harms him or makes him better, everything will be fine.  But the fact that some people have a relationship with a new person every day or have a relationship with several people at the same time, for example, they commit a great sin because in addition to harming others, they also destroy themselves.  But in today's world, because raising children is very difficult.  If you have sex with him, be sure to agree whether you intend to have children or not.  should be limited to marriage and adultery is a sin, the reason is that marital relations are outside of marriage.  causes serious damage in terms of spirit.  If this framework is maintained in any relationship and that relationship does not harm you, there is no problem.

Comment: Remember that answers are to be given here based on Islamic knowledge, not on personal opinions.